# How to preserve GPX track point (trkpt) info when performing ogr2ogr with sql ST_union operation

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, gpx, multipoint

I am performing GDAL ogr2org operation with ST_union(Geometry) on tracks from GPX file to split those at intersection points. Track points have elevation and depth info. In GPX track point entry looks like this:

```
    <trkpt lat="51.1012332738" lon="20.916904">
      <ele>130</ele>
      <extensions>
        <depth>12.3</depth>
      </extensions>
    </trkpt>
```

The command being executed is this:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt MULTILINESTRING -dsco GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES -lco FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES  -f GPX "%output_gpx%" "%input_gpx%" -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_union(Geometry) from tracks"
```

The problem is that resulting GPX file looses depth and elevation data.
The question is how to keep depth and elevation data in resulting GPX file after ST_union(Geometry)?

Sample GPX file: [DOWNLOAD](https://www.mediafire.com/?7au9s64fxdxfer6)

Comment: Could you put some sample of the "input.gpx" somewhere?

Comment: Here you are: https://www.mediafire.com/?7au9s64fxdxfer6

Answer (score 1):

In OGR, the elevation data gets stored in a point layer called `track_points`. You can do "normal" ogr2ogr operations preserving the elevation data like this:

```
 ogr2ogr -f GPX output.gpx input.gpx waypoints routes track_points
```

However, that fails on your ST_UNION command because you requested a Multilinestring (which has no vertex elevation data by definition).

Comment: Will command you provided split tracks at intersection point and preserve depth data?

Comment: It preserves the depth data, but does no intersecting. Intersecting will only work with lines, not with points. But lines have no depth data, only points have it.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to work around this issue?

Comment: Not yet, I will try what is possible...

Comment: For instance like making complex SQL query joining track and point data?..

Comment: GPX format contains structural data does not suit well for editing with GDAL which follows the simple feature model: features are points, lines, polygons or collections and each feature has one set of attribute data. In GPX the tracks (lines) are formed from trackpoints and as you describe, points contain their own attribute data. I would search for special GPX tools. Pushing data with ogr2ogr into Spatialite and combining elevation data from the trackpoints table with track vertices with SQL and spatial joins should be doable but tricky.

Comment: I imagine SQL query could look somewhat like this "SELECT ST_union(Geometry) FROM track_points GROUP BY track_fid ORDER BY track_seg_point_id ASC".

Comment: Query works but does not do the right thing. It creates (slowly) 4 multipoints without any elevation data. `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite lake.gpx -sql "SELECT ST_union(Geometry) as geometry, track_fid, track_seg_point_id FROM track_points GROUP BY track_fid ORDER BY track_seg_point_id ASC"`